# Javafx TitledPane resize Header

Tags: java, javafx, resize

Is there a way to size the header of the TitledPane to the size of the GridPane?

[image]

Here is the code for the TitledPane

```
        // --- GridPane container
    final Label label = new Label("N/A");
    TitledPane gridTitlePane = new TitledPane();
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();

    gridTitlePane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #336699;");
    gridTitlePane.setPrefSize(parentGrid.getPrefWidth(),parentGrid.getPrefHeight());
    gridTitlePane.setText("Statistik");
    gridTitlePane.setExpanded(false);
    //grid.setVgap(4);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
    grid.add(new Label("To: "), 0, 0);
    grid.add(new TextField(), 1, 0);
    grid.add(new Label("Cc: "), 0, 1);
    grid.add(new TextField(), 1, 1);
    grid.add(new Label("Subject: "), 0, 2);
    grid.add(new TextField(), 1, 2);
    grid.add(new Label("Attachment: "), 0, 3);
    grid.add(label,1, 3);
                                                    gridTitlePane.setStyle("");
    gridTitlePane.setContent(grid);

    HBox hbox = new HBox();
    //HBox.setHgrow(gridTitlePane,Priority.ALWAYS);
    //HBox.setHgrow(grid,Priority.ALWAYS);
    hbox.getChildren().setAll(gridTitlePane);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a fixed size to your `TitlePane` header simply in a css file:

```
.titled-pane > .title {
    -fx-pref-height: 36.0;
}
```

or you can set the height using the `lookup(String)` function of `Node`

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
            Pane title = (Pane) titlePane.lookup(".title");
             title.setPrefHeight(value);
             //or
             title.prefHeightProperty().bind(gridPane.heightProperty());
            });
```

Comment: Can't I do like this `gridTitlePane.setStyle("-fx-width:100%","-fx-height:100%")`? And can I be able to resize the pane in runtime like IntelliJ idea output window?

Comment: The dynamic height of Title can be achieved using something like this method.
https://github.com/JPro-one/JPro-tickets/issues/147#issuecomment-1501767227